# vue.js keyup, keydown events one character behind

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using the keydown/keyup events which call a javascript function that prints the value of input box to the console (and also the value of the currentTarget field of the event), and I am noticing it is a character late. For example, if I type **hello** into the input box, I only see **hell** in the console, until I press another key and then I see **hello**, even though by this point I've typed **hello1**. Why is this? And is there anyway around it?

Here's the HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form__field" v-model="keywords" v-on:keyup.enter="queryForKeywords" v-on:keydown="queryForKeywords">
```

And the JS:

```
queryForKeywords: function(event) {
        var self = this;
        if (this.keywords.length > 2) {
            console.log("keywords value: " + this.keywords);
            console.log("event value: " + event.currentTarget.value);
    }
```

Comment: the value of the currentTarget probably isnt updated until the event finishes being handled (so things like event.preventDefault can be called).  You probably should grab the character directly off the event and append it to the currentTarget value

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of doing just that but I thought there may be a more graceful solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are depending on the input's `v-model` to update the `keywords` property, the value won't update until the Vue component has re-rendered.

You can access the updated value of `keywords` in a callback passed to [`this.$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) like in this example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { keywords: '' }
  },
  methods: {
    queryForKeywords: function(event) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.keywords.length > 2) {
         console.log("keywords value: " + this.keywords);
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" class="form__field" v-model="keywords" v-on:keyup.enter="queryForKeywords" v-on:keydown="queryForKeywords">
</div>
```

Comment: In Vue 2.6.*  You need to replace the "keydown" with "input"  Example:  @input="queryForKeywords"

Comment: This will work but the problem doesn't hides in vue.js rather that the keydown event which fires the method when the input value is not updated yet.

Answer (score 6):

> ## The real problem doesn't has to do with vue.js at all

**The problem hides behind the `keydown` event!**

So when the event fires, the input value is NOT updated yet. [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9d7vwnu1/1/)

[MDN - keydown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event)

In general, `keydown` it is used for informing you which key is pressed. And you can access it like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  console.log(e.key)
}
```

---

As solution, you can use the `keyup` event: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wma7e3pq/10/)

My recommendation is to use a [custom v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) using `:value` and the `@input` event.

```
<input type="text" :value="keywords" @input="queryForKeywords">
```

And the script:

```
  data: {
    keywords: ''
  },

  methods: {
     queryForKeywords(event) {
       const value = event.target.value
         this.keywords = value
       if (value.length > 2) {
            console.log("keywords value: " + this.keywords);
       }
    }
  }
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/e9msyg4j/2/)

Answer (score 5):

The currently accepted answer is for an old version of vue, in the latest versions should be used @input instead of keypress or keyup.

Comment: Replacing `@input` with `@keyup` fixed the timing problem for me.