# keydown & keyup in Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, frontend

This is my code

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="temp">
<div>
<input type="text" v-on:keydown = "storeValue">
<p>{{ value }}</p>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" v-on:keyup = "storeValue2">
<p>{{ value2 }}</p>
</div>
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
    el:'#temp',
    data:{
        value:'',
        value2:''
    },
    methods:{
        storeValue:function(event){
            this.value = event.target.value
        },
        storeValue2:function(event){
            this.value2 = event.target.value
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

[image]

There are two textboxes. 
In my opinion, the two textbox's final result should be same, if I put a value in the textbox. 
However, the result is different.
value shows "w" after I enter any key. (I trigger it again)
value2 shows the "w" immediately. 
So does someone can explain it?

Check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4pea057/)

Thank you so much.

@Vladislav Ladicky
I try the plain javascript. However, the keydown and keyup behavior is the same.

```
<html>
    <p>This is keyDown</p>
    <input type="text" id="myInputKeyDown" onkeydown="keyDownFunc()" >
    <p id="demo1"></p>

    <p>This is keyUp</p>
    <input type="text" id="myInputKeyUp" onkeydown="keyUpFunc()" >
    <p id="demo2"></p>
</html>

<script>
    function keyDownFunc(){
        let temp = document.getElementById("myInputKeyDown").value;
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = temp;
    }

    function keyUpFunc(){
        let temp = document.getElementById("myInputKeyUp").value;
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = temp;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I believe this would answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913579/vue-js-keyup-keydown-events-one-character-behind

Answer (score 1):

Your issue can be easily fixed with the help of two-way data binding feature of Vue like in above answer by @TechBirds. Below is the snippet with minor changes which resolves your issue of updating. I've also added a watcher in there which will be of great help if you want further control over your input box value.

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="temp">
<div>
<input type="text" v-model="value1">
<p>{{ value1 }}</p>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text"v-model="value2">
<p>{{ value2 }}</p>
</div>
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
    el:'#temp',
    data: {
       value1:'',
       value2:''
    },
    watch: {
      value1: 'storeValue1',
      value2: 'storeValue2'
    },
    methods:{
      storeValue1(value) {
        // you can play here for more control
      },
      storeValue2(value) {
        // you can play here for more control
      }
    }
})
</script>
```

12345678

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the keydown event looking like one keystroke behind in terms of showing data.

Check [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) of VueJs, for a data change there is a DOM re-rendering. In this case it looks like the timing of keydown and the said re-rendering is causing it to look like the keydown is one character late.

At the time of keydown being triggered, storeValue is triggered,
It looks like the `event.target.value` is not yet updated therefore you wont see it being set to `value`

Answer (score 0):

I think it have nothing to do with Vue. Try it with plain JS and you will get the same results. It's classical problem with keydown/keyup. And reason why everybody is using input event instead.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="temp">
<div>
<input type="text" v-model="value">
<p>{{ value }}</p>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text"v-model="value">
<p>{{ value }}</p>
</div>
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
    el:'#temp',
    data:{
       value:''
    },
    methods:{
    }
})
</script>
```

do you want this ?

Comment: Please don't write code-only answers; instead, explain why your code might solve the OP's problem. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20178028).